# Dificuldade em realizar update usando Codeigniter3 + Ion Auth

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

Tenho uma aplicação CI3 juntamente com a biblioteca [Ioon Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/tree/3) para CI3, recentemente o projeto passou por algumas atualizações e agora será uma aplicação multi cliente, ou seja, um único banco de dados para vários clientes. Com isso surgiu a necessidade de salvar as sessões no banco de dados para que pudéssemos acompanhar quais usuários estão logados e qual empresa pertence, na tabela onde serão guardados as sessões dos usuários, além dos campos padrões que o CI precisa, foram criados campos personalizados, os quais preciso realizar a inserção de dados.

Eu sei que em CI utilizamos `$this->session->set_userdata()` para passar campos adicionais, no entanto, essas informação são guardadas no campo **data** da tabela. A minha tabela de sessões está da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ion_users_sessions (
    id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "data" text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    "identity" varchar(255) NULL,
    email varchar(255) NULL,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    company_id int8 NULL,
    old_last_login int8 NULL,
    last_check int8 NULL,
    last_activity int8 NULL,
    ion_auth_session_hash varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ion_users_sessions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX last_activity_idx ON public.ion_users_sessions USING btree (last_activity);
```

Os campos abaixo de **data** são os campos personalizados, como não consegui preencher na hora em que a sessão é criada pelo CI, eu estou tentando realizar o update baseado no **ID** da sessão. Estou utilizando o seguinte código realizar o update:

```
    public function update_session()
    {
        $data = array(
            'identity' => $this->session->userdata('identity'),
            'email' => $this->session->userdata('email'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'company_id' => $this->session->userdata('company_id'),
            'old_last_login' => $this->session->userdata('old_last_login'),
            'last_check' => $this->session->userdata('last_check'),
            'ion_auth_session_hash' => $this->session->userdata('ion_auth_session_hash')
        );

        $where = array(
            'id' => session_id()
        );

        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($where, false);
        $this->db->update('ion_users_sessions');

        print_r($this->db->affected_rows());

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Ao executar a função, sempre recebo a quantidade de linhas afetadas como **0**, no entanto, ao recuperar a ultima query usando `$this->db->last_query()`, é possível copiar a mesma e jogar diretamente no PgAdmin que funciona sem problema.

***Existe alguma forma de preencher os campos personalizados na hora em que a sessão é criada? Se não for possível, como posso contornar o problema?***